# How do I load javascript file that's located in external server dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to load a javascript file that's stored in an external server.I  tried using plain js to do so in the following manner:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    scriptObject = document.createElement('script');
    scriptObject.type = 'text/javascript';
    scriptObject.async = true;
    scriptObject.src="https://seal.verisign.com/getseal?host_name=esewa.com.np&amp;size=S&amp;use_flash=YES&amp;use_transparent=YES&amp;lang=en",
});

$(window).load(function(){
                document.getElementByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptObject);      
            });
```

Since Js is single threaded and the file loading procEss took a lot of time i tried using ajax and js to do so in the following manner

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    scriptObject = document.createElement('script');
    scriptObject.type = 'text/javascript';
    scriptObject.async = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:"https://seal.verisign.com/getseal?host_name=esewa.com.np&amp;size=S&amp;use_flash=YES&amp;use_transparent=YES&amp;lang=en",
        dataType: "script",
        success: function(data) {
            scriptObject.src= data ;
            $(window).load(function(){
           document.getElementByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptObject);   
            });
        }
    }); 

});
```

However I am not sure if one can load .js file in the way that i have done with ajax and jquery. Is there a better way for doing this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There already exists wonderful jQuery function for that http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/